# How to pass arguments with special characters and spaces to C-Shell script

Tags: shell, arguments, parameter-passing, special-characters, csh

I am writing a generic commands executor shell script generic_script.csh .
Basically it contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/csh -f

foreach x ("$argv")
   $x 
end
```

Usage: `generic_script.csh "ls -l" "groups" "mkdir /tmp/abc"`

Expected output: execute the commands in arguments in sequence.

Problem: 
when I parse $argv in foreach loop,

1. if I use `$argv`, arguments are split by spaces:

```
ls
-l
groups
mkdir
/tmp/abc
```

2. if I use `"$argv"`, $x has `ls -l groups mkdir /tmp/abc` as value.

How can I split the arguments based on "" i.e

```
ls -l
groups
mkdir /tmp/abc
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best you can do is call them like `generic_script.csh \"ls -l" \"groups\" \"mkdir /tmp/abc\"` . You may even need to use anywhere from 2 to 5 back-slash escape chars for each `"`. Not really worth the trouble. You might be able to `cat cmd_file | foreach line ; $line ; end`. In general, you don't want to spend much time working with `csh` as it has many traps and limitations. The one you are playing at now would be one of those limitations. `bash` or `zsh` will give you many more features to play with. All, IMHO of course. Good luck.

Comment: If you really much continue using `csh` get a copy of the Anderson's Guide to the Csh (or similar title). It is a modle of good technical writing and will make you a true power user of `csh` but ... if you get really good with `csh`, you'll reach a point where you'll find there are tasks you cannot do using the limited syntax of `csh`, you'll need to use other tools to achieve your goal (from personal experience ;-) ). AND read thru this https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html  ... Good luck!

Comment: @shellter Thanks for the info. as you said it started to get too cumbersome once the args got json special characters. I ended up writing the commands to file, execute it and delete the same after execution.

Answer (score 0):

The array `argv` has the right elements, it's just that the foreach syntax splits them up.  However getting an element using `$argv[3]` will work.

This forces us to loop over the numbers from 1 to `$#argv` instead.

So as far as I know we are stuck doing the following:

```bash
set i=1
while ($i <= $#argv)
    echo "i=$i"
    echo "$argv[$i]"
    @ i = $i + 1
end
```

Which gives the following output

```
$ csh test.csh a b "C D E"
i=1
a
i=2
b
i=3
C D E
```

Since your example seems like a list of arbitrary length, you need to have an actual loop instead of using `$1`, `$2`, ... but in another context, you could use those and they would not be split up:

```bash
echo "1: $1"
echo "2: $2"
echo "3: $3"
```

```
csh test.csh a b "C D E"
1: a
2: b
3: C D E
```

I was preparing test questions in BASH but just now learned that they need to be in doable in any one of bash, ksh, sh, csh.  Now I'm learning that csh doesn't do functions... great!